# How to use CSS to add a newline in JavaScript based buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created the table using  [DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/).
It looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to split them like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that with customized CSS?
My HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.2/css/dataTables.colVis.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./src/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./src/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./src/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>


    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.sortable-table').DataTable( {
                // Allow column selection, based on this
                // https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/
                "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
                // Except first column,
                // it should stay.
                // https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/options
                colVis:{exclude:[0]}
            });
         } );
         </script>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
        margin:150px;
    }
    img {
        max-width:65%;
        max-height:65%;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Experiment 11</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2> G. Shared functional  annotation</h2>
    Here the functional analysis is scored with <tt>-log(Pvalue)</tt>.
    <h3> LN </h3>
    <table border="1" class="dataframe sortable-table display compact pure-table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: left;">
      <th>GO</th>
      <th>FOO</th>
      <th>BAR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>                regulation of response to wounding</td>
      <td>  6.850</td>
      <td> 11.975</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**As Per your example:**

```
<div class="ColVis" >
  <button class="ColVis_MasterButton">
    <span>Show / hide columns</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

> This is your **html** for that button now we are applying **css** to it

```
 .ColVis{
    width:100%
}
button.ColVis_Button{
    float:right
}
```

> Provide **Width 100%** to your Colvis class and **FLOAT:right** to button.

**Note** :

If possible then apply **new class for colvis** and for **button** because if you change style of **colVis** then maybe it will change style in your other **template** or in your other **layout** so test it first.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/urxk3q0z/2/

> When you see output in jsfiddle first starch the size of output screen 
>   so you can see proper output

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule to your CSS:

```
div.ColVis {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after reviewing your code then hopping on the ColVis website and inspecting their search and show/hide button, I have come to the conclusion! I need to see your CSS because, at the moment, the way they have it is predefined to inherit from the parent class. So, if you want to adjust the predefined css then manipulate this: `button.ColVis_Button, ul.ColVis_collection li`, this is the class hierarchy they use to move the button around. Just add the `!important` tag to the things you need changed.